# Angular - CMS returns HTML content that can contain instances of routerLink: how to compile them? Any workaround?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives

I am facing the following (apparently simple) situation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <p>{{text}}</p>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  public text: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) {}

  @Input() id: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.text = this.apiService.getText(id);
    });
  }
}
```

The variable `text` comes from a CMS and can contain manually written instances of `routerLink` (well, actually of a custom directive that extends `routerLink`).

Is there any non hacky way to make those directives compile, when `ngOnInit` is called? It has to work with AOT. Any proposal of workaround is welcome.

Notice that the parent component is under "resolve", so `this.route.params.subscribe` will always emit a value straightaway after being called.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough clout to comment and I don't mean to state the obvious, but since you are using Angular 5 with AoT have you looked at [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use regular `<a href>` instead of `<a routerLink>` in the CMS and then parse the `<a href>`s to route correctly. This also separates your CMS from your Angular application.

I've written this post on how you can do this with a Directive:

[Can Angular 2 parse links received from external CMS to be resolved as internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427502/can-angular-2-parse-links-received-from-external-cms-to-be-resolved-as-internal/49675312#49675312)

That solution used window and document which won't work well with AOT but those functions are pretty easy to rewrite.